# Implementing a buffered transform stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am trying to implement a stream with the [new Node.js streams API](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1) that will buffer a certain amount of data.  When this stream is piped to another stream, or if something consumes `readable` events, this stream should flush its buffer and then simply become pass-through.  The catch is, this stream will be piped to many other streams, and when each destination stream is attached, the buffer must be flushed *even if it is already flushed to another stream*.

For example:

1. `BufferStream` implements `stream.Transform`, and keeps a 512KB internal ring buffer
2. `ReadableStreamA` is piped to an instance of `BufferStream`
3. `BufferStream` writes to its ring buffer, reading data from `ReadableStreamA` as it comes in.  (It doesn't matter if data is lost, as the buffer overwrites old data.)
4. `BufferStream` is piped to `WritableStreamB`
5. `WritableStreamB` receives the entire 512KB buffer, and continues to get data as it is written from `ReadableStreamA` through `BufferStream`.
6. `BufferStream` is piped to `WritableStreamC`
7. `WritableStreamC` also receives the entire 512KB buffer, but this buffer is now different than what `WritableStreamB` received, because more data has since been written to `BufferStream`.

Is this possible with the streams API?  The only method I can think of would be to create an object with a method that spins up a new PassThrough stream for each destination, meaning I couldn't simply pipe to and from it.

For what it's worth, I've done this with the old "flowing" API by simply listening for new handlers on `data` events.  When a new function was attached with `.on('data')`, I would call it directly with a copy of the ring buffer.

Comment: A doubt: does data move only in 512KB bursts or only the first one is 512KB ?

Comment: @user568109 When something begins receiving data from the buffered stream, it should receive the initial 512KB buffer (only once) and then will continue to receive data as it passes through the buffered stream as data becomes available.  Only the first chunk is 512KB (or whatever the size of the buffer is).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my take on your issue.

The basic idea is to create a `Transform` stream, which will allow us to execute your custom buffering logic before sending the data on the output of the stream:

```
var util = require('util')
var stream = require('stream')

var BufferStream = function (streamOptions) {
  stream.Transform.call(this, streamOptions)
  this.buffer = new Buffer('')
}

util.inherits(BufferStream, stream.Transform)

BufferStream.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
  // custom buffering logic
  // ie. add chunk to this.buffer, check buffer size, etc.
  this.buffer = new Buffer(chunk)

  this.push(chunk)
  done()
}
```

Then, we need to override the `.pipe()` method so that we are are notified when the `BufferStream` is piped into a stream, which allows us to automatically write data to it:

```
BufferStream.prototype.pipe = function (destination, options) {
  var res = BufferStream.super_.prototype.pipe.call(this, destination, options)
  res.write(this.buffer)
  return res
}
```

In this way, when we write `buffer.pipe(someStream)`, we perform the pipe as intended and write the internal buffer to the output stream. After that, the `Transform` class takes care of everything, while keeping track of the backpressure and whatnot.

Here is a [working gist](https://gist.github.com/PaulMougel/7961469). Please note that I didn't bother writing a correct buffering logic (ie. I don't care about the size of the internal buffer), but this should be easy to fix.

Comment: I think this is close but not 100% correct. Until pipe is called for the first time, the transform implementation needs to put everything onto the buffer, then once pipe is called, then switch to calling this.push.

Comment: also what about the `_flush()` method

Answer (score 1):

Paul's answer is good, but I don't think it meets the exact requirements. It sounds like what needs to happen is that everytime pipe() is called on this transform stream, it needs to first flush the buffer that represents all the accumulation of data between time the transform stream was created/(connected to the source stream) and the time it was connected to the current writable/destination stream.

Something like this might be more correct:

```
  var BufferStream = function () {
        stream.Transform.apply(this, arguments);
        this.buffer = []; //I guess an array will do
    };

    util.inherits(BufferStream, stream.Transform);

    BufferStream.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {

        this.push(chunk ? String(chunk) : null);
        this.buffer.push(chunk ? String(chunk) : null);

        done()
    };

    BufferStream.prototype.pipe = function (destination, options) {
        var res = BufferStream.super_.prototype.pipe.apply(this, arguments);
        this.buffer.forEach(function (b) {
            res.write(String(b));
        });
        return res;
    };


    return new BufferStream();
```

I suppose this:

```
BufferStream.super_.prototype.pipe.apply(this, arguments);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
stream.Transform.prototype.pipe.apply(this, arguments);
```

You could probably optimize this and use some flags when pipe/unpipe are called.

Comment: the problem with this of course is that it is buffering all the data, and it never stops buffering, so this can easily cause memory "leaks" unless you're careful. Probably fine for short-lived programs but not servers etc.